# Creating interiors in Unity

Tags: unity, level-design, map-editor

I'm trying to use the vanilla Unity Editor to make some interiors (with primitives like cubes etc). It's a hard process by itself because you have to do all sorts of calculations for scale and position of the primitives but it gets worse when I have to make a door or a window, which requires me to divide a primitive into smaller ones and do even more calculations (again, all by hand, which usually come out wrong and make the game look like crap)

How can I avoid this whole process? Is there a way to simply slice a primitive like you do in BSP mapping?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you are using primitives over meshes? The engine shines if you import custom models. So you can avoid the tedious process of modeling in unity by modeling in a program that is actually designed for that.

The only other way I know off creating something like a door in unity without using multiple primitives is coding a mesh for it by hand. Which is probably even worse then your method.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with any 3D program, that's why. I thought that designing it from the engine directly gave me more control over what is made and that I'd be sure what the exact dimensions of everything were.

Comment: Designing meshes are on a whole different level then designing levels. I can create a basic door in less then a minute with 3D max or blender. In these programs you can setup the scale, if you can select 1 unit = `1 meter` or `1cm` or `1 inch` it will all be scaled accordingly when exporting. You can build complex textures inside the texture editors and they will be exported and within a blink imported into unity attached to your mesh. And this is only the tip of the iceberg since a 3D app offers just so many tools to help out.

Comment: Just download blender, watch a UI tutorial and one that creates a mesh with basic things like bevel and extrude and you are set.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is practically impossible. The primitives are there just for prototyping/placeholders. You will have to "get" those from outside of Unity. Or you can look at asset store, there are some assets sold that can do limited 3d modeling.

Answer (score 1):

To build level geometry within Unity, probably the best tool available is ProBuilder: http://www.protoolsforunity3d.com/probuilder/

However, the usual approach is *don't* build your level geometry within Unity. Build the level geometry in a 3D modeling tool, like Maya or Blender, and import that into Unity.